# MySQL get 2 days before without calculate weekend

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to calculate 2 days ago in MySQL without counting Saturday and Sunday? My data sample:

```
Wednesday, 20 Sept 2017
Thursday, 21 Sept 2017
Friday, 22 Sept 2017
Saturday, 23 Sept 2017
Sunday, 24 Sept 2017
Monday, 25 Sept 2017
Tuesday, 26 Sept 2017
Wednesday, 27 Sept 2017
```

When I run query on `Friday, 22 Sept 2017`, I will get the first data (`Wednesday, 20 Sept 2017`)

When I run query on `Saturday, 23 Sept 2017`, I will get the second data (`Thursday, 21 Sept 2017`)

When I run query on Sunday, 24 Sept 2017, I will get the third data (`Friday, 22 Sept 2017`)

But when I run query on Monday, I won't get any data

And when I run query on Tuesday, I will get the fourth data (`Saturday, 23 Sept 2017`)

And when I run query on Wednesday, I will get both of fifth data and sixth data (`Sunday, 24 Sept 2017 && Monday, 25 Sept 2017`)

My query so far:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE (status_id = '2' AND date_added LIKE CONCAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -2 DAY),'%')) OR (status_id = '21' AND date_modified LIKE CONCAT(DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -2 DAY),'%'))
```

It works to count 2 days before, but it still count Saturday and Sunday. Basically, I create a query that runs everyday to auto change status a data that have been 2 days with a status. For example, in Wednesday, I will change any data in Monday that have `status_id 2` (for example). In the other words, Saturday data will be processed on Tuesday. Sunday data will be processed on Wednesday, including Monday data, it will be processed on Wednesday too

Comment: Is it necessary to calculate this in query?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What happens to a weekend day?  If we can't count weekend days, then how do we even move off Saturday or Sunday?

Comment: is the date column is varchar datatype or is it a date(time) datatype. The example data suggests it's a varchar field.

Comment: sorry for confusing, I have to run a query everyday using cron, this query is to do automated system to change the status of my data. The status will be changed every two days for each data, but it won't count saturday and sunday (it will be skipped) it will count again on monday

Comment: my data is datetime

Comment: You lost me at the part where querying on Tuesday gives you Saturday.  This is totally unclear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for confusing, but as I edited above, Basically, I create a query that runs everyday to auto change status a data that have been 2 days with a status. For example, in Wednesday, I will change any data in Monday that have status_id 2 (for example). So in other words, Saturday data will be processed on Tuesday. Sunday data will be processed on Wednesday

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you asking.  Come back here when you can clearly articular your logic.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry but that's what I can say... Process many data every day, for each data has been 2 days, I will change the status. But it won't count Saturday and Sunday... I can create these function on PHP but what my team wants is a query, not a php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I do is set the cron job between monday to friday, so saturday and sunday will not count. Also, these job is better to do in PHP not in SQL. Thanks for any comments and answer